Nodejs server connects with public AWS RDS instance first time but "timesout" in subsequent attempts?
I have a nestjs app that connects to a remote public AWS RDS instance via TypeORM.
When I first launch the app the server connects to the db just fine, but when I shut down the server and restart it, the server refuses to connect to the db.
I was wondering if it is because the prev connection somehow persisted in between sessions but from the typeorm config, keepConnectionAlive is false.
Here's the config for your reference:
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.getOrThrow('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.getOrThrow('DB_PORT'),
        database: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_DB'),
        username: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_USER'),
        password: configService.getOrThrow('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        synchronize: configService.getOrThrow('DB_SYNC'),
        ssl: {
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          require: true,
        },
        entities: [
          Asset,
          User,
          UserAssets,
          UserAdvertized,
          Order,
          Notification,
        ],
        logging: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}

All this while, I am perfectly able to connect to the RDS instance via other means such as telnet etc...

What is the exact error message you are receiving?

@JohnRotenstein It's not an error message rather the connection keeps hanging. As a poor workaround I opened the access to the db for all IP addresses and then it started working. I forgot to mention that I am running 3 microservices as docker conatiners and they all attempt to connect to AWS RDS. Maybe AWS RDS doesn't allow multiple connections from the same server i.e IP address?
